# How to implement HTTP methods using fastCGI along with nginx?

Tags: c++, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to work with basic HTTP using FastCGI and Nginx in c++. I have found the link for fastcgi here: http://chriswu.me/blog/getting-request-uri-and-content-in-c-plus-plus-fcgi/

But there is no clear distinction for HTTP methods like GET and POST. Also, I am unable to figure out how to perform redirection of url using fastcgi. P

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience with fastCGI and nginx, but since I have used CGI/Apache and took a look of fastCGI samples, I can suggest the following things (and risk to fail with the answer):

- GET request is part of URL, so I would parse `const char* uri = FCGX_GetParam("REQUEST_URI", request.envp);` to check if parameters are given (i.e. if there are key/value pairs after the question mark).
- If the previous condition is false, then check if media type in the header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (meaning it's a POST) and parse HTTP request body to obtain key/value pairs. More info on that can be found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)
- To perform redirection, use the [example](http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/) but modify response to return HTTP redirection response as described at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx).

Perhaps fastCGI offers more advanced functions, so all of these can be achieved in a fancy way.